# Is there a concise way to include php variables in HTML?

Tags: php

All of the text on my page has to come from a translation file, so my markup is littered with stuff like `<?php echo $translation; ?>`.

For just one or two calls, it's fine, but when it's all over the page, it makes things awfully verbose. Is there a more concise way to include PHP variables in the markup? I can echo a heredoc, but then it removes all the IDE features for HTML editing like automatic indentation and highlighting.

Is there a way to just do something like `{$translation}` instead of `<?php echo $translation ?>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is '<?=' the same as 'echo'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236135/is-the-same-as-echo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [method for creating PHP templates (ie html with variables)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905696/method-for-creating-php-templates-ie-html-with-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<?=$translation?>
```

If you have activated short_open_tag in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Smarty for example is supported in an IDE like netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Use a template language, like [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), it has builtin support for internatiolzation with a simple syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep "pure" PHP, you can use `<?=$translation?>`, or you can use a template engine, like Smarty. There are tons of those, just find one that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29